# Prop value not updating to be sent via Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, laravel-blade

**Description**

I've got an input field which will send an Axios request via a debounce function. The value that is already present in the input field is generated by Laravel. When a user updates the value in the field, I need this value to then be sent via the Axios request.

I'm not sure if it's an actual Prop value I need to look at changes for, or if I need to store the updated value in the `data()` part of Vue.

**edit-personal-details.blade.php** (included on another view)

```
<edit-personal-details name="{{ $cv->display_name }}" location="{{ $cv->location }}" phone="{{ $cv->contact_number }}" email="{{ $cv->email_address }}"></edit-personal-details>
```

**EditPersonalDetails.vue** (component)

```js
<template>
    <div class="grid grid-columns-2 grid-gap-8">
        <div>
            <label>
                <span class="block font-bold mb-2 text-grey-500 text-sm">Display Name <i class="fad fa-question-circle leading-none text-blue-400" data-tippy-content="The name that will appear on your CV"></i></span>
                <input type="text" :value="name" @input="updateDisplayName" class="bg-grey-200 border-2 border-grey-200 hover:border-grey-300 focus:border-blue-300 outline-none p-3 rounded text-grey-700 text-lg transition w-full font-semibold">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import _ from 'lodash'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
const Toast = Swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  position: 'top-end',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 3000
})

export default {
    props: ['name'],
    methods: {
        updateDisplayName: _.debounce(() => {
            axios.post('url', {
                display_name: this.name
            })
            .then(response => {
                // Show success
            })
            .catch(response => {
                Swal.fire({
                    type: 'error',
                    title: 'Error'
                });
            })

        }, 1500),
    }
}
</script>
```

How exactly do I detect that the value of the Prop has changed, and then push that into the Axios request?

I need to be able to populate data, but also make that data editable at the same time and once Vue detects a change, update it.

EDIT: I've tried to use watchers and computed but couldn't get it inside the Axios request.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I believe that `name` should be `:name` in order to be a prop value.

Comment: Hi @nakov do you mean when binding the value on the field or within the Axios request? Either way, when I look at the value with Vue Build Tools the value does not update for that prop when I change the value in the input. It's almost like it needs `v-model` added to it, but when I do that it throws errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `:value` to set the value, and not getting it from the `updateDisplayName` function. You should be passing the `event.target.value` instead of the *"static"* value. But a better way to solve it is to use a data property with `v-model`

The other problem (I see) is that you're mutating a prop inside the component. Run-time Vue will let you do that, but if you may get the warning: *"Avoid mutating a prop directly"*

The prop should be treated as immutable form the perspective of the component, meaning that the component should not attempt to change it. Given that you're using PHP to generate those values render-time, those values are not going to change. If you want a passed prop to be mutable by the component, you should copy the value into the component's instance.

```js
export default {
    props: ['name'],
    data: function () {
      return {
        name_val: this.name
      }
    },
    methods: {
        updateDisplayName: _.debounce(function(){
            axios.post('url', {
                display_name: this.name_val
            })
            .then(response => {
                // Show success
            })
            .catch(response => {
                Swal.fire({
                    type: 'error',
                    title: 'Error'
                });
            })

        }, 1500),
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" @input="updateDisplayName" v-model="name_val">
```

#### TL;DR;

You **could** solve it without copying the initial value into data just doing this:

```html
<input type="text" @input="updateDisplayName" v-model="name">
```

but it's not a good idea (refer to the warning mentioned above) or link: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Prop-Mutation-deprecated

#### update

Also, as @skirtle pointed out, should use `function` instead of array function in the debounce function. Looks like lodash is using `function.apply` to bind a context (https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L10333)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for this. I've changed my code to match your suggestions, but I get the error: 'Cannot read property 'name_val' of undefined' when I run the function. I've checked and the data 100% exists and the input does successfully change the value. Any idea as to why this would be happening?

Comment: @Matt The arrow function passed to `debounce` will lead to an incorrect `this` value. Try a normal function instead.